# Second order equations on manifolds

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, manifolds, vector-bundles

In my notes, the lecturer considers a smooth vector field $v: TM\to T(TM)$, with $M$ a smooth manifold. Let's write

$$v(u,e)=((u,e), (a(u,e),b(u,e)).$$

It is said that $v$ is a second order equation if $T\pi_M\circ v=\text{id}$. It implies that $a(u,e)=e$, i.e.

$$v(u,e)=((u,e),(e,b(u,e))).$$

Here, my notes claim that if $c(t)=(u(t),e(t))$ is a curve on $TM$ satisfying the above, then

$$\frac{du}{dt}=e(t), \ \frac{de}{dt}=b(t)$$

This is probably very stupid but I can get why...

Answer (score 2):

The requirement for v(u,e) that a(u,e) = e is called "obeying [the canonical flip on the double tangent bundle](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Double_tangent_bundle#Canonical_flip_and_associated_coordinates)"; it is precisely the vector fields on the double tangent bundle that satisfy or obey the canonical flip that are called second-order ODEs on a closed, connected, smooth manifold M.

For a second-order ODE on a manifold v(u,e), if c(t) = (u(t),e(t)) is a solution, then u(t) is called a "base curve" on the manifold M and its derivative c(t) is the solution to the second-order ODE; this is one of the reasons that v(u,e) is called a second-order ODE.

For more information on the canonical flip, try [*Transveral Mappings and Flows* by Abraham and Robbin](https://smile.amazon.com/Transversal-mappings-flows-Ralph-Abraham/dp/B0006BR4GQ/); for more information second-order ODEs on manifolds, try [*Foundations of Mechanics* by Abraham and Marsen](https://smile.amazon.com/Foundations-Mechanics-2nd-Ralph-Abraham/dp/080530102X)