# Vector Field on Tangent Bundle that is Simultaneously a Gradient Field and Hamiltonian Field?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A second-order differential equation on a smooth manifold is a smooth section of the double-tangent bundle that satisfies the canonical flip -- that is, a map $\xi: TM \to TTM$ which satisfies $\xi(q, v) = (q, v, v, w)$.

My question is, is there a second-order ODE on a (hopefully closed, but not necessarily so,) connected Riemannian manifold, say,  $S^1$ or $\mathbb{R}$ -- that is to say, a vector field on $\xi: TS^1 \to TTS^1$ (i.e., on the tangent bundle to the circle, which is vector bundle isomorphic to the infinite cylinder) or $\xi: T\mathbb{R} \to TT\mathbb{R}$ (i.e., on the tangent bundle to the real line, which is vector bundle isomorphic to the the plane) -- which obeys the canonical flip and which is simultaneously a gradient vector field and a Hamiltonian vector field?

See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254585/second-order-equations-on-manifolds) for some background information on second-order ODEs on manifolds. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308397/difference-between-a-hamilton-and-a-gradient-vector-field) for a definition of gradient and Hamiltonian vector fields. I'm not sure how important [the Hodge decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301184/vector-field-decomposition-into-gradient-and-hamiltonian-vector-field) is, but here is [some background on the Hodge decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology#Hodge_decomposition) on closed, connected Riemannian manifolds and [the Helmholtz decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) on $\mathbb{R}^3$

Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I only know naive differential geometry, so let me know if I've misunderstood your question.

We consider the vector field $f(x,v) = (v,w)$ on $\mathbb R^2$.

Such a vector field is Hamiltonian if and only if it arises from a Hamiltonian of the form $H(x,v) = U(x) + \frac12v^2$, so $w = -\partial U(x)/\partial x$ is a function of $x$ alone.

As $\mathbb R^2$ is simply connected, the vector field $(v, w)$ is a gradient field if and only if its "curl" $\partial w/\partial x - \partial v/\partial v$ is zero everywhere, so $w = x + c$ for some constant $c$.

Thus the only vector fields on $\mathbb R^2$ that satisfy your conditions are $(x,v)\mapsto(v,x+c)$. Such a vector field

1. corresponds to the second-order ODE $\ddot x = x+c$,
2. is the gradient of the scalar field $(x,v)\mapsto (x+c)v$, and
3. is a Hamiltonian vector field with Hamiltonian $H(x,v) = -\frac12(x+c)^2+\frac12v^2$.

Comment: I think this is perfect! The function $w=x+c$ is harmonic on ℝ, so that jibes with my other post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2028283/do-hamiltonian-vector-fields-correspond-to-co-closed-1-forms-on-a-closed-connec (to be clarified). Thanks so much for the answer!

Comment: Glad to help. P.S. You don't have to keep editing your comment. :)